# Dynamics Crm insert record with SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-2016

With SSIS, I want to insert a record in a CRM table (Contact). In the ownerid field I am inserting the ID of a team, since the owner of the record is a team. But this insertion is not possible, it looks like the system only looks for users and not teams as owners:

> [Dynamics CRM Destination [94]] Error: An error occurred with the
>   following error message: "System.Exception:  (1)  Error: systemuser
>   With Id = cc3b2c21-62d2-e611-80dc-3863bb351f50 Does Not Exist

How can I insert a record specifying that the ownerid must be searched in the teams table?

Edit (in reply to  Pawel Gradecki's comment): these are the records about the owner in the Contact entity:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set also OwnerIdType which is 8 for a SystemUser and 9 for a Team.
[image]

Update: Just to prove this column is available for mapping, I created a SSIS package that connects to an Online deployment of mine and mapped Contact. Here is the screenshot of how the columns look like:

[image: Online connection for contact]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the field OwnerIdType, maybe you talk about Dynamics NAV?

Comment: no, I'm talking about CRM. Check again, I've edited my answer with a screenshot. Maybe you did not map the field in the source, that's why you don't see it in destination.

Comment: Ah, maybe you are talking about a field that is present in the SSIS integration toolkit? Because OwnerIdType does not exist in the Contact entity.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. Every entity that is User owned (and contact is such entity) has this field. Go to the database and run: SELECT OwnerId, OwnerIdType  FROM [ContactBase] if you don't believe me. So this is not any "integration toolkit" specific field.

Comment: Maybe post some screenshot what are you exactly doing, because from you comments I have doubts what are you trying to achieve and how.

Comment: I have edited the question with the fields in the Contact entity. We use CRM 2016 online.  @Pawel Gradecki

Comment: You should tag your question as crm online. What connector are you using in SSIS? It does not matter that you don't see the field in CRM, because it is not a field visible from UI. But you can set it in Kingswaysoft SSIS Connector (and I assumed you are using it?). I just checked for my online deployment and the column is there and it can be mapped. Can you share your SSIS configuration?

Comment: It is a colleague of mine that has this problem with SSIS, so I will tell him about this field ownerIdType....thank you!

Comment: Just to add, you could either have an input of integer value which represents the entity type code of the lookup entity, that can be 8 (for systemuser) or 9 (for team) for owneridtype field, or otherwise, it can be the lookup entity name in text format which can be "systemuser" or "team" (lower case).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: When using SSIS (I am using Kingswaysoft) To assign the owner as a user, use owneridtype = 8

I have no idea why it is 8 instead of 1 as the official d365 documentation suggests, but I found this forum post which suggested 8 and it worked.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/407667/invalid-error-type-invalid-owneridtype-10076-in-dynamics-crm-2016

Someone can improve this answer by telling us where to find the integers needed for the other types of owner (ie teams).

It is really baffling that the integer to input is 8 instead of 1 as the documentation suggests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/ownershiptypes?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

Comment: Entity type code of 1 is for account entity. The ownerid field can only be associated with systemuser (which has an entity type code of 8) or team (which has an entity type code of 9). You could use entity name such as "systemuser" or "team" as the input for the owneridtype field as the alternative to the integer input value.